# EF Core global entity filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, entity-framework-plus

I'm looking for a way to apply a global filter to my entities in EF. I stumbled upon [EF plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/) but I'm having some issue filtering my related entity.
My current setup looks like this:

I have a `TenantEntity`, which inherents from `Entity`, it contains stuff like `CreatedUtc`, `UpdatedUtc`, `Id`, `TenantId` and other general stuff.

```
public abstract class TenantEntity : Entity
{
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have a generic `MultitenantRepository`, this is where the filtering is applied (currently with EF plus):

```
public class MultitenantRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : TenantEntity
{
    public MultitenantRepository(DbContext context, ITenantProvider tenantProvider)
    {
        this.TenantProvider = tenantProvider;
        this.Context = context;

        this.Context.Filter<TEntity>(e => e.Where(w => w.TenantId == tenantProvider.GetTenantId()));
        this.Context.Filter<TEntity>(e => e.Where(w => w.DeletedUtc == null));
    }
}
```

I create a new MultitenantRepository for every entity in my db, so for example for the `Team` entity, I will create it like this:

```
public class TeamRepository : MultitenantRepository<Team>
{
    public TeamRepository(DbContext context, ITenantProvider tenantProvider)
        : base(context, tenantProvider)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Team> GetAll()
    {
        return OkayrContext.Teams
            .Include(t => t.Members)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.Employee)
            .AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

And this is where the problem occurs, the `Team` and `TeamMember` (`Team.Members`) entity both inherent from `TenantEntity`.
But if I call `UnitOrWork.TeamRepository.GetAll()`, it will filter out the deleted `Team`s but not the deleted `TeamMembers` within the team.

Is there some way to filter those out without having to extend all of my queries?

Comment: The idea behind [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) is that you define them during model creation(in `OnModelCreating`) via `HasQueryFilter` so you need to inject your `ITenantProvider` into your `DbContext` and try to use it in the `HasQueryFilter` expression. I would start with trying to add `ITenantProvider` as a parameter of `DbContext`, but not sure that this will work.

Comment: Also, *if* EF-plus has some way of adding filters later, you make the existence of filters on an entity type depend on whether or not a repository was instantiated for that entity in a context's life time. That's highly error-prone, because navigation properties can go anywhere off of one entity type (as you experience here).